# how to get match string that start with hyphen and character with regex

Tags: regex

I have two strings

```
100-2000
```

and

```
100-X200-2012
```

I try to write regex that match both strings like below by saying that if the second hyphen start with X ignore it

```
[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9 \-X]+-[0-9]
```

but it fail to match it, I am not sure how to match it with my criteria ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if the second hyphen start with X ignore it"? Perhaps post some examples of strings you do *not*  want to be matched by this regex.

Comment: Should the regex accept second string as well?

Comment: From the regex tag's tooltip (which I suggest you read): *"Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."*

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified a tool, I'll go with the .NET regex flavor (my personal favorite):

```
\d+(-[ \w-[_X]][ \w-[_]]+)?-\d+
```

`\d` is the same as `[0-9]`

In .NET, you can use [character class subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction) to remove particular elements from a characters class. In this case, I've included a space and a `\w` (which is the same as [0-9a-zA-Z_]) within the character class and then subtracted the underscore and uppercase X.

Another option is to use negative lookahead:

```
\d+(-(?!X)[ 0-9a-zA-Z]+)?-\d+
```

I like this even better, but not all flavors of regex support it.

Comment: Thanks, its match the second string but its not match with the first one at the same time

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this:

```
[0-9]+-[^X][a-zA-Z0-9 \-]*-[0-9]+
```

Comment: `[^X]` will match any character except 'X', including all whitespace (such as tabs and newlines) and non-alphanumeric characters (anything on the keyboard and much more, basically).

Comment: @Cyborgx37 OP mentioned just X, nothing more. I did what he said.

Comment: I drew my conclusions from the feeble regex attempt: `[a-zA-Z0-9 \-X]+`. Looks to me like an attempt to use character class subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this

```
(\d*)(-X\d*|)-(\d{4})
```